# Image problem in IE 7

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer-7

I am developing a site using asp.net and C# ( framework 1.1 ).
Theres a provision for the user to upload his photo and the upload performs in 2 steps
1. User selects a photo and the photo is displayed for review
2. Database call is made and it is uploaded to the server

In IE6 the photo is shown in review mode ( from the users system )
But in IE7 it is not shown unless it is uploaded to the server.

Is there any workaround for this????

Comment: So when the photo is being shown in review mode, the img src is a path on the user's own drive?

Comment: yes
the path is on the users drive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely a security related issue. IE6 probably accepts to display images with paths from local disk, which might be a security vulnerability. Also try it in firefox, my guess is that will not work either. So you are left with uploading the photo in step 1 and just do the database stuff in step 2; Or do not show the photo for review...

Answer (score 0):

This really depends how you store the photo temporarily before showing it back to the user for review. Are you storing it in a temporary file? Is it a blob in memory? It should be showing, so I'd check that it is actually loading and not just hidden by some stupid CSS difference. Use IEDevToolbar to see if there is actually an image there. If it is, use Fiddler to see if the file is actually coming down in the browser.

Unfortunately there's too many variables for me to take a stab at this one, sorry.